# Objective C - why are instance variable declared in implementation section not recognized in main?

Tags: objective-c

In implementation section I declare the variable:

```
double n_YTD_t;
```

In main:

```
NSLog(@"New YTD Sales are: %f ", n_YTD_t);
```

generates the following error:

> use of undeclared identifier: 'n_YTD_t'

Comment: Show the .h file, probably the declaration is in the wrong place.

Comment: Trying to access a class' ivar from a totally unrelated function?

Answer (score 1):

`main` doesn't have any object to access.  You need to provide an instance of your class:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
    MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"New YTD Sales are: %f ", obj.n_YTD_t);  // assuming it's a property
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `n_YTD_t` in a completely unrelated implementation file for an object. The variable is out of scope for `main`; you must instantiate an instance of your class and access the variable from that if its an instance variable. If it's global and file-wide, then you need to import the file that declares it.

You should consider looking through [Apple's Documentation on Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html), look through tutorials ([like these ones for iOS development](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)) and maybe [read a good book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023562.do), since you don't seem to understand the basics of the language.

Comment: the above person answered the question for me.  Your comment was incorrect, condescending and rude.  Get a life.

Comment: I gave the same answer as the "correct" one as well; you needed to initialize an instance of your class. Read the first two lines. I also included the scenario if it was a class variable, aka a standard C file-wide global. Either way, you _didn't_ understand the basics of the language or OOP. In no way did I mean to be condescending or rude, as I too am a beginner; I simply made and observation and attached some resources I thought would help you. Maybe my text is too dry, and I should add some smiley faces or disclaimers... :|